# position: fixed on left push content

Tags: html, css

So i have a navbar on the left of my website it works fine, but it wont "push" the footer like normal data does

```
#navbar {
    float:left;
    width: 181px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
#footer {
   border-top:2px solid #a1a1a1;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   color:white;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background-color: #101010;
}
```

this is the css, you can see a "working" version at:

[version - no data](http://aardwolfbootcamp.com/lizza/)

[version - with data](http://aardwolfbootcamp.com/lizza?content=yes)

with the second link you will notice how the main content pushes the data, but on the first one if you have a small screen or make the window small it wont show all of the nav bar, is there a way to fix this?
i believe i have covered everything

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, when the page is resized vertically you want the footer to stop when it reaches the `navbar`.

One possible solution is to modify `.navbar` css like below:

```
#navbar {

  // remove these styles
  // float: left;
  // position: fixed; 
  // height: 100%; 

  width: 181px; // keep this
 }
```

To get the footer to rest at the bottom of the nav, you need to get the `.navbar` back into the document flow, `float:` and `position: fixed` take it out of the document flow.

You still may want to make this `float:left` for part of your design, in which case you'll need something else to extend down to stop the footer (probably something in the `content` section).

Comment: i could easily remove those, but i also still want the navbar to maintain its position so that on long pages it stays on the screen rather then goes to the center of the text

Comment: @TomHancock I don't think you can achive what you want with pure html and css. You would have to involve javascript so you can check when the bottom of the sidebar has reached the footer. There are a bunch of so called [Sticky Sidebar](https://www.google.se/search?q=sticky+sidebar&oq=sticky+sidebar&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i65j69i60l2j0l2.2186j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) plugins out there.